# How is this code causing a few second pause?

Tags: java, debugging, awt, lag

Before you read this, understand that I know there are much better ways in writing this code. 
 This code was made a long time ago and I know much more about Java than I used to.
 Nevertheless, I recently viewed the code and wish to figure out what's causing the problem so I know in the future.

 **UPDATE: 
I have downloaded an experimented with JProfiler. It turns out, there is a huge spike in memory allocation on line 158 when I draw the string. However, I don't know what it exactly means or why it causes a huge lag spike.**

```
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if (isVisible) {
        for (int i = 0; i < debugList.length - 1; i += 2) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.setFont(font);
            try {
                g.drawString(debugList[i] + ":", xPos, yPos + (i * 15)); // Line 158
                g.drawString(debugList[i + 1], xPos, yPos + 10 + (i * 15));
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                if (!errorDisplayed) {
                    System.out
                            .println("There was a problem while displaying the debug variables. Check to make sure you added all of the variables you declared in the debug constructor");
                    errorDisplayed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A while back I was making a little 2D platformer game and had to bugfix. I figured that a cool way to bug fix was to have a debug class that will display variables on the screen. Turns out, it works great! It displays all the variables on the screen with no problems!

However, when I call the `changeVisible()` **(at the very bottom of the code)** method after I hit a key, it freezes my whole thread for around 3 seconds.

It's not all that important as it's already obsolete with other debug classes I made, but I would still like to know what's causing the spike for future projects.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Debug {
    private String[] debugList;
    private boolean errorDisplayed = false, isVisible = true;
    private Color color;
    private int xPos = 0, yPos = 0, currentIndex = 0;
    private Font font;
    /**
     * This constructor will create an array that can fit (numberOfVars)
     * variables
     * 
     * @param numberOfVars
     *            - The amount of variables you wish to display
     * @param setVisible
     *            - Will toggle visibility on instantiation (true):on
     *            (false):off
     */
    public Debug(int numberOfVars, boolean setVisible) {
        debugList = new String[numberOfVars * 2];
        if (setVisible)
            isVisible = true;
        else
            isVisible = false;
        color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        xPos = 20;
        yPos = 30;
        font = new Font("SanSerif",Font.BOLD,12);
    }

    /**
     * This constructor will create an array that can fit (numberOfVars)
     * variables
     * 
     * @param numberOfVars
     *            - The amount of variables you wish to display
     * @param setVisible
     *            - Will toggle visibility on instantiation (true):on
     *            (false):off
     * @param inputXPos
     *            - The location of the text on the x axis
     * @param inputYPos
     *            - The location of the text on the y axis
     */
    public Debug(int numberOfVars, boolean setVisible, int inputXPos,
            int inputYPos) {
        debugList = new String[numberOfVars * 2];
        if (setVisible)
            isVisible = true;
        else
            isVisible = false;
        color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        xPos = inputXPos;
        yPos = inputYPos;
    }

    /**
     * This method will initialize the variable you wish to display
     * 
     * @param objectName
     *            - the display name of the variable
     * @param arg
     *            - the value of the variable you wish to display
     */
    public void addDebug(String objectName, Object arg) {
        if (currentIndex + 2 <= debugList.length) {
            debugList[currentIndex] = objectName;
            debugList[currentIndex + 1] = arg.toString();
            currentIndex += 2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will change the text color
     * 
     * @param newColor
     *            - the color of the debug text
     */

    public void changeColor(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }
    /**
     * This method will change the text font
     * @param font
     *          - the font of the debug text
     */
    public void changeFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
    }
    /**
     * This method will update the variable value
     * 
     * @param objectName
     *            - the name of the variable you wish to display (must be the
     *            same name used in addDebug())
     * @param arg
     *            - the value of the variable you wish to display
     */
    public void update(String objectName, Object arg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < debugList.length; i += 2) {
            if (debugList[i] != null && debugList[i].equals(objectName)) {
                if (i < debugList.length + 1)
                    debugList[i + 1] = arg.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will draw the debug information
     * 
     * @param g
     *            - The graphics you wish to paint on
     * @param lineSpacing
     *            - The display space between the variables
     */
    public void draw(Graphics g, int lineSpacing) {
        if (isVisible) {
            if (currentIndex == debugList.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < debugList.length - 1; i += 2) {
                    g.setColor(color);
                    g.setFont(font);
                    try {
                        g.drawString(debugList[i] + ":", xPos, yPos
                                + (i * lineSpacing));
                        g.drawString(debugList[i + 1], xPos, yPos + 10
                                + (i * lineSpacing));
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        if (!errorDisplayed) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("There was a problem while displaying the debug variables. Check to make sure you added all of the variables you declared in the debug constructor");
                            errorDisplayed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method will draw the debug information
     * 
     * @param g
     *            - The graphics you wish to paint on
     */
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (isVisible) {
            for (int i = 0; i < debugList.length - 1; i += 2) {
                g.setColor(color);
                g.setFont(font);
                try {
                    g.drawString(debugList[i] + ":", xPos, yPos + (i * 15));
                    g.drawString(debugList[i + 1], xPos, yPos + 10 + (i * 15));
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    if (!errorDisplayed) {
                        System.out
                                .println("There was a problem while displaying the debug variables. Check to make sure you added all of the variables you declared in the debug constructor");
                        errorDisplayed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will toggle the visibility of the debug display
     */
    public void changeVisible() {
        isVisible = !isVisible;

    }
}
```

Main class (Lines commented with Debug are important):

```
package com.bustedearlobes.platformergame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Game extends Applet implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int pixelSize = 3;

    public static double sx = 0, sy = 0, dir = 0;

    public static Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(700,560), pixels = new Dimension(windowSize.width/pixelSize,windowSize.height/pixelSize);

    public static Point mousePos = new Point(0,0);

    public static boolean isRunning = false,
            isMoving = false,
            isJumping = false,
            isMouseLeft = false,
            isMouseRight = false;

    public static String name = "2D Game";

    public static Level level;
    public static Character character;
    public static Inventory inventory;
    public static Sky sky;
    public static ArrayList<Mob> mobs = new ArrayList<Mob>();
    public static ArrayList<BrokenBlocks> brokenBlocks = new ArrayList<BrokenBlocks>();
    public static Spawner spawner;
    public static Sound sound;
    public static GameFile gameFile;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static Tile tile;
    public final static double GRAVITYCONSTANT = 1;

    private Image screen;

    public static Debug debug = new Debug(5,false); //Debug

    public Game() {
        setPreferredSize(windowSize);

        addKeyListener(new Listening()); //Debug this is where the key listener is that calls the changeVisible() method
        addMouseListener(new Listening());
        addMouseMotionListener(new Listening());
        addMouseWheelListener(new Listening());
    }

    public void start() { // Defining all the objects required
        requestFocus();

        tile = new Tile(); // Loading Images...
        gameFile = new GameFile();
        level = new Level();
        character = new Character(Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize * 2);
        isRunning = true;
        sound = new Sound();
        inventory = new Inventory();
        sky = new Sky();
        spawner = new Spawner(10);
        debug.changeFont(new Font("San Serif",Font.PLAIN,10)); // Debug
        debug.addDebug("Player", character); // Debug
        debug.addDebug("Side X", sx); // Debug
        debug.addDebug("Side Y", sy); // Debug
        debug.addDebug("Sky", sky); // Debug
        debug.addDebug("Level.animation", level.animation); // Debug
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public void tick() {
        character.tick();
        level.tick(pixels.width / Tile.tileSize + 2,pixels.height / Tile.tileSize + 2);
        sky.tick();
        inventory.tick();
        for (int i = 0; i < mobs.toArray().length;i++)
            mobs.get(i).tick();
        for (int i = 0; i < brokenBlocks.toArray().length;i++)
            brokenBlocks.get(i).tick();

        debug.update("Player", character); // Debug
        debug.update("Side X", sx); // Debug
        debug.update("Side Y", sy); // Debug
        debug.update("Sky", sky); // Debug
        debug.update("Level.animation", level.animation); // Debug
    }

    public void render() {
        Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(new Color(100,100,255));
        g.fillRect(0,0,pixels.width, pixels.height);

        sky.render(g);
        level.render(g,pixels.width / Tile.tileSize + 2,pixels.height / Tile.tileSize + 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < brokenBlocks.toArray().length;i++)
            brokenBlocks.get(i).render(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < mobs.toArray().length;i++)
            mobs.get(i).render(g);
        character.render(g);
        inventory.render(g);
        debug.draw(g); // Debug
        g = getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(screen,0,0,windowSize.width,windowSize.height,0,0,pixels.width,pixels.height,null);
        g.dispose();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setTitle(name);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        screen = createVolatileImage(pixels.width, pixels.height);
        while(isRunning) {

            tick();
            render();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you using this code? Post your main class .

Comment: -1 for catching `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

I can't immediately see what the problem is, except possibly the fact that `debugList` is a list and not a HashMap. (Not sure how big an impact this has.)

But, I can tell you how to find out yourself. Check out a tool called JProfiler. It allows you to see line-by-line execution times in your code, which will let you see where the bottleneck is. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290227/1872981).

Comment: I have downloaded an experimented with JProfiler. It turns out, there is a huge spike in memory allocation on line 158. See my post for more details