# Can JProfiler show the time spent on each line of a method?

Tags: jprofiler

when performance profiling with JProbe you can view the time spent on each line of specific methods.

Is there an equivalent feature in JProfiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no source code view where you could see each line with an associated time measurement. However, JProfiler can record line numbers, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290227/936832

Note that in that case, the displayed line numbers in the call tree refer to the parent nodes.